# Validate id attribute in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0

In my request have around 500 child elements and those elements have attribute id, id is optional element. I have used bellow code snip to convert my request id attribute.

```
<xsl:if test="@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Is there any way to do the `<xsl:if test="@id">` validation in common place that affected to all the places. Otherwise I have to check this in every places.

Please advice me. Than you...

Comment: That does not make sense to me. Why would you test if there is an `id` attribute and then make one, if there already is one? Please explain the purpose of this. Also show more XSLT code, your input XML, the output you get and perhaps your XSD (since you tagged the question with `xsd` and mention validation).

Comment: If I used without <xsl:if test="@id">, In request have element without id attribute in my transformation out put element has id without value.like this <Add id=""/>. I don't want to create id attribute if it is not in the request. Because of that I have used the test if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That snippet essentially copies the `id` attribute from the input to output if one exists, and does nothing otherwise. This whole snippet can be replaced by

```
<xsl:copy-of select="@id"/>
```

since `copy-of` does nothing if the selected node set is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that your code is doing anything other than copy what's already there.

In any case, if you want to apply a *transformation* to all elements that have an `id` attribute, write a template matching the attribute, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:attribute name="new-id">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

This will keep the existing value and rename the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would start a stylesheet with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

which copies everything level by level, node by node. Then you can add templates for element and/or attributes that need special treatment.

Now as long as you ensure that your templates for elements do `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="@id"/>` the attributes are copied.

If you want to transform an element then add a template doing e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/Address">
  <Add>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </Add>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: '<!-- Changing Tags -->
<xsl:template match="/Address">
  <Add>

  </Add>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="all">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>' this is my code and my input xml is '<Address id="Address_SepoS1Iv1V"> 
 <abc>ABC</abc>
</Address>' But it is not creating attribute id in out put.

Comment: Please note that I wrote `mode="#all"` and `mode="#current"`. As for changing an element, do note that you need to do apply-templates. I will edit and show that.

Comment: If I used "mode="#all" and mode="#current" I'm getting bellow error An attribute whose value must be a QName or whitespace-separated list of QNames had the value '#all''
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'

Comment: That sounds as if you don't use an XSLT 2.0 processor as http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#modes would allow what I wrote. Then don't put any `mode` attributes at all on `xsl:template` and `apply-templates`.